# Python list issue with simulator

Tags: python, list, simulator

Hey I'm attempting to make a powerball simulator game thing for school and the final pbsim value is not printing for some reason. Also, I would like the pbsim and wb lists to be constantly changing inside that while loop, if anyone could figure out how to do that it would be much appreciated :) thanks

This code is for my school assignment where im trying to make a powerball simulator, so what I want people to do is to be able to input values into a form and this code will run and return the number of times the code had to run until a win was achieved!

`wb` and `pbsim` should be constantly random everytime it goes through the loop but it isnt currently. Also I dont want any values in the same list to repeat.

So in conclusion what I need is for pbsim and wb to be random and changing everytime the while loop == false is active

## python code

```
import random
nwb = 5     # number of winning balls
rwb = 10    # range of winning balls
npb = 2     # number of powerballs
rpb = 20    # range of powerballs

# randomly draw a list of winning balls
actual = [] 
while nwb > 0:
    x = random.randint(1, rwb)
    if x not in actual:
        actual.append(x)
        nwb = nwb - 1
        actual.sort()

# randomly draw a list of winning powerballs
pbactual = []   
while npb > 0:
    x = (random.randint(1, rpb))
    if x not in pbactual:
        pbactual.append(x)
        npb = npb - 1
        pbactual.sort()        
       

win = False
run = True
count = 0
nwb2 = nwb
npb2 = npb
wb = []     # list of randomly choosen balls 
pbsim = []  # list of randomly choosen powerballs 

while win == False:
    while run:
        x = random.randint(1, rwb)
        if x not in wb:
            wb.append(x)
            pbactual.sort()

        if len(wb) == nwb2:
            while npb2 > 0:
                x = random.randint(1, rpb)
                if x not in pbsim:
                    pbsim.append(x)
                    npb2 = npb2 - 1
            run = False



    actual.sort()
    wb.sort()
    pbactual.sort()
    pbsim.sort()
    count += 1
    print(actual, wb, pbactual, pbsim)
```

Comment: What is `form`? Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Feodoran sorry the form is where i'm pulling the data from, so you enter it in a html form and then I use that data.

Comment: Sorry, my question was not well formulated. What data does `form` hold? You should provide some example data for a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: @Feodoran oh sorry the data is just integers which can be anything really, example could be nwb = 5
nwb2 = 5
rwb = 10
npb = 2
npb2 = 2
rpb = 20
ballswin = 0
pbwin = 0

Comment: Ok, now what exactly is the problem? It is hard to guess what your code is supposed to do. Some annotations would be helpful, or at least meaningful variable names. "the final pbsim value is not printing" What is the final value? "I would like the pbsim and wb lists to be constantly changing"  Changing how?

Comment: @Feodoran sorry im kinda new to this whole coding and stack exchange thing, ill try do my best to describe everything better now

Comment: @Feodoran I have added as much explanation that I can I think! Hopefully this is better :)

Comment: `run` never becomes True again after you set it to False, and npb2 never becomes nonzero again after it reaches 0.

Comment: You seem to be expecting a lot of things to reset by themselves.

Comment: For better readability, I cleaned the code a bit and directly included the explaination for the variables. Optionally, the first two loops may be futher simplified with `actual = sorted(random.sample(range(rwb), nwb))` and `pbactual = sorted(random.sample(range(rpb), npb))`. I did not get into the last loop yet, but you can probably do some similar replacement here, to further increase readability of the code and avoid `npb2` and `nwb2`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica `run` does not have to become `True` again. But `win` is never changed, therefore the outer loop will never be left.

Answer (score 0):

some variables are zero that why it gets in infinite loop. i have changed it. changes are in **changes**. Now its shows output.

```
import random
nwb = 5     # number of winning balls
rwb = 10    # range of winning balls
npb = 2     # number of powerballs
rpb = 20    # range of powerballs

# randomly draw a list of winning balls
actual = []
while nwb > 0:
    x = random.randint(1, rwb)
    if x not in actual:
        actual.append(x)
        nwb = nwb - 1
        actual.sort()

# randomly draw a list of winning powerballs
pbactual = []
while npb > 0:
    x = (random.randint(1, rpb))
    if x not in pbactual:
        pbactual.append(x)
        npb = npb - 1
        pbactual.sort()


win = False
run = True
count = 0
**nwb2 = len(actual)
npb2 = len(pbactual)**
wb = []     # list of randomly choosen balls
pbsim = []  # list of randomly choosen powerballs

while win == False:
    while run:
        x = random.randint(1, rwb)
        if x not in wb:
            wb.append(x)
            pbactual.sort()

        if len(wb) == nwb2:
            while npb2 > 0:
                x = random.randint(1, rpb)
                if x not in pbsim:
                    pbsim.append(x)
                    npb2 = npb2 - 1
            run = False
            **win = True**



    actual.sort()
    wb.sort()
    pbactual.sort()
    pbsim.sort()
    count += 1
    print(actual, wb, pbactual, pbsim)
```